# Normal vs Cloud/Azure Hosting and role of SQL Azure vs SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure, hosting, scalability

First of all let me clear that I am not from a web background so if any of my understanding about how it works is not correct please feel free to correct me

Let's say I have a website which I would like to host on cloud because

```
- I don't want to take care of hardware
- I want to scale my website as needed
```

Now I am a bit confused between role of `SQL Server` vs role of `SQL Azure` in this case.

**Normal Web Hosting**

When I think of a normal website I know that I need a host/server on which my website will be hosted. The host should be able to support `SQL Server`. For scaling purpose I will have to host my website/ASP Pages on multiple servers. Similarly if I want to scale up my `SQL Server` I will have to host it on multiple servers and will have to make sure data is up to date in all servers through some mechanism.

**Cloud Based Hosting**

Now I think I can setup similar structure on `Cloud/Azure` as well. If yes, would I be using true capabilities of Cloud in this case?

Or should I use `SQL Azure` instead of `SQL Server`? What benefit would I get in that case?  Would I be still be responsible for for scaling up and consistency of data? I know I can scale up the website by setting the number of VMs/instance but what about scaling of database?

**Edit**
Thanks to `Florin Dumitrescu` the terminology I wanted to use was `Scaling Out` because I am more concerned about the performance rather than how big my database is in terms of size. I am more concerned about how database would scale between different servers/systems to accommodate the load and hence result in better performance

Comment: I think you are incorrectly using the [scale up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability#Scale_vertically_.28scale_up.29) terminology, when you are actually referring to [scaling out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability#Scale_horizontally_.28scale_out.29)

Comment: @ Florin Dumitrescu  you are right I meant scaling out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Azure, as Yossi mentioned, is a Database-as-a-Service. As such, you simply ask for it to be provisioned, magic happens, and you have a database that scales from 1GB to 5GB, 10GB, all the way to 50GB (soon to be 150GB as [announced](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2011/10/17/recap-from-pass-summit-2011.aspx) at SQL PASS). The nice thing about SQL Azure: you don't have to worry about any infrastructure, servers, licensing, etc. You simply connect with your connection string. SQL Azure is designed to be scalable to handle a considerable number of concurrent tenants, so you don't have to concern yourself with scaling.

SQL Azure also replicates its data in the data center, to provide "durable" storage. You still need to design a Disaster Recovery scheme, in case the data center becomes unavailable (and you can use the [Data Sync](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/features/database/#data-sync) service for that).

As far as your website itself: As you scale out to multiple instances, each instance runs the same code and uses the same resources. Taking this one step further, you can move your static (non-changing) web content, such as images and CSS, to Blob storage. This has several advantages over storing them with the website itself:

- Ability to enable the Content Delivery Network, a worldwide edge-caching service providing better performance for your end users
- Less strain on your web server instances, as requests for those images will now be directed to Blob storage, a completely separate URL than your website
- Ability to update an image or stylesheet without having to re-deploy your application - simply upload a new file to Blob storage.

I highly recommend the [Windows Azure Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8396), as there are labs that take you through the fundamentals of all of this, with complete code samples as well. This is updated almost monthly, staying in sync with the latest Windows Azure SDK and tools.

Comment: Please note that Sql Azure databases will not actually infinitely scale on themselves. Furthermore, behind the scenes, SqlAzure databases are running on shared servers. Microsoft are not giving numbers on the performance to expect from such a databases, but chances are that you are going to get much better performance with a medium priced on premises dedicated server. Starting with the end of 2011, Sql Azure Federations will be available and they will indeed offer a way to scale with Sql Azure databases: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2281.aspx

Comment: @Florin - if you set the db to use business edition and max size to 50GB, the database will grow automatically, and bill you on a daily amortized basis at the current usage tier (in increments of 10GB). Same with Web edition if you set max size to 5GB. As the database grows and shrinks beyond and under the 1GB mark, your daily billing will adjust accordingly.

Comment: if by scaling you meant automatically increasing the disk size of the DB, then I agree with you. What I actually meant was scaling from the performance point of view, that is the load that the database can take. Sorry if I was ambiguous on that.

Comment: If you are worried about horizontal scaling you might want to look at Table Storage depending on the type of domain objects/structure/functionality you website requires.

Comment: Florin Dumitrescu is right I meant scaling out. Can you guys help in accordance with my latest edit. Apologies for inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

If you're hosting your web site in the cloud, and you need a database, than SQL Azure is almost certainly the best option.

SQL Azure is a database as a service, so you'll create your database and work against it from your code, but not have to worry about the provisioninig, there are no servers as such, it is all being taken care of.

From an application point of view it looks and behaves pretty much like SQL Server, so initially all that changes is the connecting string

Answer (score 1):

As other noted SQL Azure takes away your concerns about setting up and taking care of  the infrastructure. This is part of the premise of Azure in general which is to provide a platform rather than just Infrastructure.

The price you pay for that are some limitations on the capabilities (vs. regular SQL). Limitation on the size (at least until Federation will be available) and increased latency (since your database is not running on the same server of your app)

Microsoft Teched has as "[SQL Azure Performance and Elasticity Guide](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sql-azure-performance-and-elasticity-guide.aspx#SQL_Azure_Performance_Checklist)" which you should probably take a look at